# Accents in the integrated VSCode (Code - OSS) terminal

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

In the integrated `vscode` terminal on `Linux` version, I cannot enter accents.

When I do, for example `á` or `é` appears `a` and `b` respectively.

This appears in all methods of terminal in `vscode`, but don't appears in the rest of the app, only in the integrated terminal.

However, if I can enter rarer characters like `ñ # ~ €`.

It only happens with accented words (`á é í ó ú`), this in my language is fundamental and mandatory.

In others terminal emulators works fine.

> Same problem in xubuntu 20.04

Comment: Same thing for me... did you find a workaround?

Comment: Same problem here. I think this is a regression. I've filled a [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118466) on VSC github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has resolved in production since Mar 8, 2021 [issues/118466](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118466).